# How to use client-side-validations with chosen

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation, jquery-chosen

I have a such form:

```
= simple_form_for @post, validate: true do |f|
  = f.association :topic, input_html: {class: "chosen"}
  = f.submit :submit
```

and client_side_validations-simple_form (2.1.0). Topic_id's presence is set as true.

How to make it work together?

Now errors are loading only after submitting form and re-rendering template.

Comment: What you explain is the expected behaviour. What were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: So I want it to show me an error (if I haven't chosen anything in list) before I clicked a submit button as it should be with any other field.

Comment: You're looking for AJAX validation then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've solved an issue. It didn't worked because validation was defined this way:

```
validates :topic, presence: true
```

But client-side-validations expects validations that applied to topic_id attribute.

The solution is to apply validation to association id, not to association:

```
validates :topic_id, presence: true
```